# Return true if every item is unique in an Arraylist

Tags: arrays, arraylist

small question and code; I need the method to return true if all items in the ArrayList are correct. Why isn't this solution working, and just receiving an AssertionError?

```
public boolean unique() {
        for(itemStock item: stock) 
            if (stock.equals(item))
                return false;
        return true;

    }
```

I have wrote the equals method to return true if the calling object and parameter object have the same values for all attributes

```
public boolean equals(itemStock other) {
    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(other.name))
        if(priceUnit == other.priceUnit)
            if(quantityRemain == other.quantityRemain)
                return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `stock.equals(item)` where `stock` is an ArrayList and `item` one of the items.

What you need is to check if an item is present more than once in the list:

```
for (itemStock i1 : stock) {
    int count = 0;
    for (itemStock i2 : stock) {
        if (i1.equals(i2)) count++;
    }
    if (count > 1) return false;
}
return true;
```

If your items are comparable or hashable, you can put the into a new `set`. If they are all unique, then the newly-created set will have the same size as your list.

Comment: Ahhhh okay, I didn't think of making a new item to compare, don't know why it seems so obvious now that you have pointed it out. Thanks for the help